# Why is Github's GraphQL API 401ing with Axios?

Tags: javascript, github, graphql, axios

I'm trying to `GET` github's graphQL endpoint using `axios` but it keeps bouncing me by saying that I'm not authorized:

```
const handleClick = token => event =>
  axios.get("https://api.github.com/graphql", {
    headers: { "Authorization": "bearer" + token}
  }).then(response => console.log(response))
```

And I get back this error:

```
GET https://api.github.com/graphql 401 (Unauthorized)
bundle.js:1475 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at createError (bundle.js:1475)
    at settle (bundle.js:1619)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (bundle.js:1028)
createError @ bundle.js:1475
settle @ bundle.js:1619
handleLoad @ bundle.js:1028
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a space between "bearer" and your token:

```
"bearer " + token
```